Propane tank too close to ground rod?
My propane tank for my home was leaning at a really bad angle after it was set in place. It wasnt too bad at first, but it got worse. I waited until it was empty to move it so I could regrade the slabs it is setting on. On doing so I found the reason it was tilting so bad. One one the corners of the setting pads was on a ground rod for the electric panel in the house. I do not have any other place to put the setting pads. Out of the picture, and just to the left of the tank is the power meter and networking interface.
Between the downspout, greenery, length of flexible line into the house, window location, electrical/utility stuff, the tank has to go were it was. So I notched the setting stone. Just as fate would have it, the base of the tank and the ground rod is about 2" apart. Is there any reason, lightning or surges, that would cause an arc that would open up the side of my home in a most unexpected way?



I don't know why I didn't think of it at first, but I could have just cut it off, duh. I still would like to know if it is a problem.

Is the ground rod in-use (connected to anything)? I don't see your utility hookup in the wide shot, which is usually where I'd expect the ground rod to be.

@NickT, I got lazy and didn't dig down. It is about 3 feet diagonally from the meter. I wholly expect it to be used. I thought about digging around it to expose the wire, so I didn't rip it off the post while driving, but I recall when taking a few out, the dirt does not want to release from the post.
